# How to fill tables of a word document programatically

Tags: java, ms-word

I have been given a `Microsoft Word Document`, with some tables and spots to fill in automatically. I am not sure if this can be done with JAVA, *which is my most preferable language*.

I am looking for a way to implement a function which I can give the `word file` to it, and it fills the required spots for me. Is it possible to do it? A hint or a link to a tutorial would definitely suffice. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895012/accessing-table-embedded-in-a-word-document-using-java

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions Word store documents as [zipped XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).  Have you filled out the form manually in Word and done a before/after comparison on the XML?  Depending on the extent of the changes you could use the standard Java XML APIs to do the same thing programmatically.

A bit of googling and I found [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).  I haven't used either personally, but it appears that what you're asking for is certainly possible.  See [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleTable.java) from the POI SVN repo on how to manipulate tables.

Comment: In fact, the word doc is given to me, and I am supposed to fill different parts of it with my program. Is it gonna work? Given that I did not create the file myself (with any program)?